# How to update getTBSCertificate() method

Tags: java, x509certificate

I want to show that if I modify one bit or byte from a given X509 certificate the signature verification results false (because this modification results different hash value from the certificate). I'm stuck in the case that how to do the modification on the certificate using getTBSCertificate() method. My following code does the verification process perfectly BUT I tried to make it fail using bit or byte modification's idea but it doesn't work. Note that this idea that I proposed is to proof that any modification on the certificate will make a failure while signature verification

```
public class VerifyX509 {
private static Certificate getCACert;
private static Certificate[] getCert;

public static void main(String[] args) throws CertificateEncodingException {
    setURLConnection("https://www.google.com");
    X509Certificate x509cert= (X509Certificate) getCert[0];
    byte[] b= x509cert.getTBSCertificate();
    b[0] = (byte) ~b[0];
    // HOW TO UPDATE getTBSCertificate() after flipping the b[0] to make Verify() in my method verifySign() return false!
    verifySign();

  }


public static void setURLConnection(String link){

    try{
        int i=1;
        URL destinationURL = new URL(link);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        getCert = con.getServerCertificates();
        for (Certificate c : getCert) 
        {
            if (i==2)
            {
                getCACert= c;
                return;
            }
            i+=1;
        }
        }catch (Exception e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error while connection! Check your Internet Connection.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }

}


public static boolean verifySign()
{

        try
        {
            getCert[0].verify(getCACert.getPublicKey());
            return true;
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e2)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to make sort of test? Why dont you extend Certificate for example?

Comment: Yes it is a test. But I'm required to show the counterexample when someone flip or change any bit from the certificate, verify() must return false

Comment: So maybe extending Certificate and reimplementing getTBSCertificate so adding a setter method would work?

Answer (score 0):

All what you have to do is to get the row data DER-encoded certificate information (TBS part) and you can extract it as below

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.connect();
Certificate userCert[] = con.getServerCertificates();
        X509Certificate x509cert = ((X509Certificate) userCert[0]);


    byte[] tbs=x509cert.getTBSCertificate();
```

Then copy the content of the array b to another array bcopy through a loop and do what ever modifications you want (i.e by using the masking technique Anding with x55) after that you can get the hash value through

```
String sha1 = "";
MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        crypt.reset();
        crypt.update(bcopy);
        sha1 = byteToHex(crypt.digest());

private static String byteToHex(final byte[] hash)
{
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (byte b : hash)
    {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }
    String result = formatter.toString();
    formatter.close();
    return result;
}
```

at this point you have the hash value of the modified certificate, you can go now and extract the signature from the original certificate [ `byte[] sig= x509cert.getSignature();` ] and decrypt the signature to get the hash value and compare it with the modified hash value, good luck ;)